# Cod 400 , message: wrong latitude, OpenWearher: getting current weatherData

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-null-safety, dart-html

I'm getting error (wrong latitude) when I'm trying to get current weather data. can anyone tell me what went wrong
I tried changing locationAccuracy from low to best but it didn't change anything

```
Location location = Location();
class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  String weatherABI = '4ead5f41d1c622302dd34242f9d1c25a';
  void getlocation() async {
    await location.getCurrentLocation();
    print(location.latitude);
    print(location.longtiude);
  }

  void getData() async {
    Uri url = Uri.parse(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longtiude}&appid=$weatherABI');
    Response response = await get(url);
    print(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
      print(data);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getlocation();
    getData();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

the error :
[image]

Comment: You are calling `getData` before `getlocation` will have finished. (Note how the lat long are printed *after* the 400.) Move the two calls to `getLocation` and `getData` into an async function and `await` the result of `getLocation`. (Note that you cannot `await` inside `initState`, but you can kick off an async function from there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call your **getData()** function in the end of **getLocation()** function because both functions called at same time that's why **getData()** function does not get any location data. You need to get location first then you need to call **getData** function.

Remove **getData()** function from **initState()**

```
  void getlocation() async {
   await location.getCurrentLocation();
   getData();
   print(location.latitude);
   print(location.longtiude);
  }
```

You also need to call setState in **getData()** function once you retrieved data from the API to update your UI.

Comment: Have you explained the need to then call `setState` once the data is received?

Comment: ohh I forgot to explain let me edit my post. Thanks @RichardHeap